# Como importar dados do excel pro R?

Tags: r, microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela no excel que preciso importar para o `R`. Conseguia fazer isso tranquilamente com a função `read.csv` quando a tabela em questão estava online, mas estou tendo dificuldade para importar o arquivo direto do meu computador.

Como o código que estou fazendo será enviado para outra pessoa, não posso colocar um caminho absoluto, e estou tendo dificuldade para aplicar a função para um caminho relativo.

Answer (score 6):

Há algumas formas de fazer isso. Não consegui entender a situação muito bem, mas aqui vão algumas opções para ler arquivos Excel:

Com o pacote `gdata`:

```
require(gdata)

df = read.xls ("myfile.xlsx"), sheet = 1, header = TRUE)
```

Com o pacote RODBC`` :

```
require(RODBC)

conn = odbcConnectExcel("myfile.xlsx") # Abre uma conexao com o arquivo excel

sqlTables(conn)$TABLE_NAME # mostra todas planilhas

df = sqlFetch(conn, "Sheet1") # le uma planilha

close(conn) # fecha a conexao com o arquivo
```

Com o pacote `xlsx`:

```
require(xlsx)

read.xlsx("myfile.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")
```

Caso você não tenha problema com inglês, ainda mais outros métodos podem ser visto em: http://www.r-bloggers.com/read-excel-files-from-r/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, vejo que poderia resolver meu problema de várias formas. No fim das contas eu consegui resolvê-lo usando a função read.csv2. O código ficou assim:

setwd("C:/Users/PEDRO/PUC/TPE/Trabalho 2/G2")
file = "dados/Empresas.csv"
base = read.csv2(file, sep = ";")

O problema estava na definição do endereço do arquivo.

Comment: Se quiseres podes aceitar a resposta do @mechanical_fan, ou adicionar o teu cometário como resposta e aceita-la. Aceitar respostas que te ajudam faz parte da etiqueta do SO, e ñ é errado aceitar respostas de nós próprios.

Answer (score 3):

Atualmente, a melhor forma de importar do excel é usando o pacote [`readxl`](https://github.com/hadley/readxl). Ao contrário do pacote `xlsx`, ele não depende do `rJava`, o que o torna mais portátil e fácil de instalar.

Você pode instalar o pacote usando:

```
install.packages("readxl")
```

Exemplos de uso:

```
library(readxl)

# Abre tanto arquivos xls como xlsx
read_excel("my-old-spreadsheet.xls")
read_excel("my-new-spreadsheet.xlsx")

# É possível especificar a aba tanto por um número quanto pelo nome
read_excel("my-spreadsheet.xls", sheet = "data")
read_excel("my-spreadsheet.xls", sheet = 2)

# Se valores omissos (NA's) forem representados por outro
# valor que não seja uma célula vazia.
read_excel("my-spreadsheet.xls", na = "NA")
```

Answer (score -2):

Bem, em relação ao trecho:

"*Como o código que estou fazendo será enviado para outra pessoa, não posso colocar um caminho absoluto, e estou tendo dificuldade para aplicar a função para um caminho relativo.*"

Nós podemos saber o que colocar no caminho (`path`) através do uso de duas funções:

```
getwd()
```

e

```
setwd()
```

`getwd` é semelhante ao comando `pwd` no terminal de sistemas Linux e, retorna o caminho do diretório corrente, no qual você está. Exemplificando:

```
getwd()
```

retorna algo parecido com:

```
/home/seunome/Documents/meu.xlsx
```

`setwd` é semelhante ao comando `cd` no terminal de sistemas Linux e, muda o diretório corrente para o que você precisa. Vamos supor que o arquivo que você queira importar esteja na pasta `Downloads`, você pode fazer isso:

```
setwd(dir = "/home/seunome/Downloads")
```

E mudar o diretório de trabalho para a pasta `Downloads`:

Agora, você pode importar seu arquivo desta pasta com este comando:

```
library(rio)

lista_1 <- import_list(file = "home/seunome/Downloads/meuarquivo.xlsx")
```

Onde `"home/seunome/Downloads/meuarquivo.xlsx"` é o caminho do seu arquivo em Excel.

Este pacote (`rio`) é bem fexível e, a vantagem em aprendê-lo frente aos que foram citados nas respostas anteriores, é o de tentar padronizar a importação de dados em muitos outros formatos, não apenas em Excel, mas também `csv` por exemplo.

Maiores detalhes sobre este pacote você encontra [aqui](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/vignettes/rio.html).

Comment: Se quem deu downvote pudesse me explicar o problema da resposta para que eu pudesse melhorá-la, eu ficaria grato.

Comment: Não é nem por mim que fico questionando os downvotes, mas sim pelos usuários que podem ver a resposta (que está correta) e pensarem que esta solução é errônea ou pouco útil. Bom, citei a vignette do pacote para maiores detalhes sobre a função que utilizei na resposta.