# Organizar dados no Excel para abrir como tabela no R?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, xls, r

Tenho um arquivo com 50 observações e com 3 variáveis em arquivo Excel (.xlsx), e transformei para .csv. Utilizei `banco1<- read.csv("teste1.csv")` para criar a tabela no R, contudo as minhas 3 variáveis aparecem em uma mesma coluna. Como faço para que elas apareçam separadas?

Comment: Olá Adriana, poste algumas linhas do seu arquivo csv, provavelmente você irá precisar setar um separador diferente (e talvez também o caractere que envolve Strings). De qualquer forma, você sabia que existem pacotes que te permitem ler arquivos xlsx diretamente? De uma olhada no pacote [xlsx](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/) do CRAN.

Comment: Obrigada Anthony, consegui instalar o pacote xlsx, muito boa dica.

Comment: Adriana, se alguma das respostas atendeu a sua pergunta, você pode aceitá-la clicando no símbolo de "ok" à esquerda.

Comment: Essa pergunta também trata do assunto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19125/6036

Answer (score 5):

Pelo resultado que você observou, vou assumir que você está usando uma versão em português do Excel do Windows. Geralmente, quando salvamos uma planilha do Excel do Windows em CSV, ele é salvo com `;` como separador. Isso acontece principalmente em versões brasileiras (algumas europeias também) do Excel, pois nosso separador de decimais é a vírgula, e não o ponto, como é nos Estados Unidos.

No R isso já é, de certa forma, antecipado pela função `read.csv2` (veja [aqui](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import)), que tem a configuração de headers, decimais e separadores que o Excel do Windows usa como padrão. Veja na definição da função, fazendo `?read.csv`

```
read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
         dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...)

read.csv2(file, header = TRUE, sep = ";", quote = "\"",
          dec = ",", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "", ...)
```

Além dessa possível solução, como o Anthony disse, existem pacotes que facilitam a leitura de arquivos direto do Excel, como os pacotes `xlsx` e `gdata`. Veja [aqui](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf) e [aqui](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/gdata.pdf).

Comment: Obrigada Julio!

Answer (score 2):

Verifique os separadores no arquivo .csv, abrindo-o em modo texto. Na função `read.csv`, você deve definir o parâmetro sep. Para uma tabela com o caractere "&", como separador: , deveria utilizar

```
banco1 <- read.csv("teste.csv", sep="&")
```

Utilize também algumas destas opções para leitura de xlsx que funcionam bem é o pacote "XLConnect" (`install.packages("XLConnect")` ), que é melhor:

```
library(XLConnect)
banco1 <- readWorksheet(loadWorkbook("teste.xlsx"),sheet=1)
```

Ou então, utiizando o pacote "xlsx" (`install.packages("xlsx")`):

```
library(xlsx)
banco1 <- read.xlsx("teste.xlsx", 1 , stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Obrigada pelas dicas Guilherme!

Comment: O seu problema foi resolvido com isso, @Adriana? Eu suspeitava que o problema era como o que o Guilherme diagnosticou. Marque a pergunta como respondida.

Answer (score 0):

Outra alternativa é criar no Excel um arquivo delimitado do tipo "**Texto (separado por tabulações)**". O Excel gera um arquivo com a extensão .txt que, por experiência própria, é importado com mais facilidade pelo R Studio.

Falando de outra maneira, você deixará de usar um "comma separated values", e usará um "tab separeted value". Você também pode usar um arquivo .csv, mas precisará gastar um tempo definindo os parâmetros do read.csv.

Para posteriormente exportar um objeto chamado "mydata" para um arquivo de texto separado por tabulações chamado mydata.txt, use o comando:

```
write.table(mydata, "mydata.txt", sep="\t")
```