# Importar Tabelas do Excel no R

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor library para importar tabelas do excel para serem manipuladas em R. Gostaria de uma que me desse suporte a todas as extensões, principalmente a .xlsm.

Comment: Já tinha lido esse tópico, mas não funcionou para mim.

Comment: Lá tem 3 soluções. Uma delas é a idêntica à resposta que você aceitou..

Comment: Testei as 3 e não funcionaram.

Comment: você testou essa? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159395/6036

Comment: Instalei a library, segui o passo a passo do exemplo. Mas, logo quando eu mando montar a library com o comando library("readxl") ele já me dá uma mensagem de alerta avisando que o pacote foi feito em uma varsão anterior a do R que eu uso - a versão 3.3.3 x64. O que eu poderia fazer para solucionar isso?

Comment: esse warning não é um problema!! ele só está dizendo que a sua versão do R está desatualizada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei uma forma de fazer a leitura com o pacote `XLConnect`.

```
require(XLConnect)

dados <- readWorksheetFromFile("Pasta1.xlsm", sheet=1)
```

Aqui funcionou para um conjunto bem simples de dados salvos em xlsm.

Este pacote serve para vários tipos de arquivo excel. Mas a forma mais comum (para .xls e .xlsx) é a que havia descrito antes:

> Segundo a resposta [neste tópico do StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215381/does-the-xlsx-package-work-for-xlsm-files-in-r), é
>   possível fazer a leitura com o [pacote XLSX](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf) do R, com o comando
>   `read.xlsx` ou `read.xlsx2`. Acredito que funcione para xlsm, porém
>   não posso dizer com certeza pois nunca utilizei para este formato.
>
> Este pacote possibilita a leitura de vários formatos utilizados no
>   Excel, tais como csv, xls e xlsx. Acredito que também funcione para
>   xlsb e xlsm.

Espero que dessa vez ajude!

Comment: Testei essa função, mas não funcionou para a extensão .xlsm. Vou continuar pesquisando. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Acho que com essa edição que fiz resolve seu problema. Deu certo em um teste simples que fiz.

Comment: Consegui instalar o pacote, mas dá um erro dizendo que não foi encontrado o "perl" e também que ele foi construindo em uma versão anterior.

Comment: Isso para o XLConnect?
Porque agora que vi, tinha colocado o pacote errado no require. Era para ser o próprio XLConnect

Comment: Agora consegui acionar o pacote! Mas, ele não está localizando a planilha. Tentei incluir o caminho da planilha, mas daí dá erro de parametrização. Será como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Pode postar a mensagem de erro? (e também como você passou o caminho?)

Comment: > data <- readWorksheetFromFile("BRFS3.xlsm", sheet=2)</br>
Erro: FileNotFoundException (Java): File 'BRFS3.xlsm' could not be found - you may specify to automatically create the file if not existing.</br>
> data <- readWorksheetFromFile("D:\Folha Invest\2017\selecao\BRFS3.xlsm", sheet=2)</br>
Erro: '\F'  é uma seqüência de escape não reconhecida na cadeia de caracteres começando com ""D:\F"

Comment: Tente com:
readWorksheetFromFile("D:\\Folha Invest\\2017\\selecao\\BRFS3.xlsm", sheet=2)

O R interpreta a '\' como um caracter especial. Você precisa colocar \\ (dupla) para ele entender como parte do endereço, ou substituir pot '/'.

Avise se der certo :)

Comment: Agora deu certo! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Show :)

Abraços!